# Module not found: Can't resolve './reducers' when multiple reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm trying to combineReducers

Folder Structure

```
src
 reducers
  authReducer.js
  lojaReducer.js
  index.js
```

at Index.js i'm importing it

```
import {lojaReducer, authReducer} from './reducers';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const authPersistConfig = {
  key: 'auth',
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ['somethingTemporary']
}

export const Reducers = combineReducers ({
  authState: persistReducer(authPersistConfig, authReducer),
  lojaState: lojaReducer
});
```

but i'm getting the error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './reducers'
```

when i do only with lojaReducer it works, how can i do to import multiple reducers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the reducers are in separate files, you need to import them separately.

Something like :

```
import authReducer from './authReducer'   
import lojaReducer from '. /lojaReducer'
```

Or

```
import { authReducer} from './authReducer'   
import { lojaReducer} from './lojaReducer'
```

Depending if they are defined as `export` or `export default`